# Can AS3 non-static constants be assigned?

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor, constants

I'd like a constant instance variable in my class. The following throws an error in the constructior (of course, since I'm assigning to a constant):

```
public class Rotation {
    public const angle:Number;
    public function Rotation( angle:Number ) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

I assume there is some solution, since it is possible to create non-static constant members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know all that constant is constant, but your code can work only

> in standard mode because strict mode only allows a constant’s value to be assigned at initialization time.

Take a look on this little [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6d) from Adobe.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 2):

To provide a `public` member that cannot be set from outside, you can declare it as a `get function`

```
public class Rotation 
{
    private var _angle:Number;

    public function Rotation(angle:Number = 0) 
    {
        _angle = angle;
    }

    public function get angle():Number
    {
        return _angle;
    }
}
```